# Create linked service of REST when a token is part of the url

Tags: azure, rest, azure-data-factory, token, linked-service

my API call is of the following format url: base url/page=x&token=yyyy

How can I create a safe linked service for this in Azure Data Factory?

I tried with head auth but don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain how to do it for 1 parameter(token), you can extend it for other parameters. First create a variable to store your token. Let's call it "token_variable". You will need to pre-populate this before execution of the rest of the pipeline.
[image]

Now when you are creating the linked service, you can create a new linked service parameter to hold your token as shown below. Create your url as a concatenation of the base url and the parameter.
[image]

Now go to the dataset which you have created. You should see the token parameter available. Click on the Value field.
[image]

Create a new dataset parameter, lets call it "mytokenparm"
[image]

Now if you go back to you copy activity, you should see this parameter. You can now set it to your token_variable.
[image]
So now, if you set this token_variable to anything, it will dynamically change what is passed down to the dataset and linked service.

Since your token should be secret, it is important to set the secure inputs and outputs checkbox to true for all the activities. This is so the token cannot be seen in the history of the pipeline runs.

Comment: What if I want to create token parameter in linked service, populate it with default value and then pass it in a concat to my relative path in the dataset? It is then doesn't recognize linkedService() as valid reference...

Comment: You cannot refer to the linked service variable when setting up the dataset. You will need to use a dataset variable only in that case and build your relative path accordingly.